Can I use any valid TSQL in a SSAS multidimensional partition source query?
If I change the definition in Visual Studio, the project is fine as long as my TSQL syntax is fine.
However, when I try to process my partition, I get an error message about incorrect syntax
For instance, I tried to use variables
DECLARE @MinDateKey INT, @MaxDateKey INT;
SELECT @MinDateKey = 20240801, @MaxDateKey = 20240802;

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE DateKey >= @MinDateKey AND DateKey < @MaxDateKey

Or a stored procedure
EXEC dbo.Test_Eric

Is it possible to use any valid TSQL as source query?
